# How to rotate an image in an after pseudoelement with styled components

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have a dropdown menu with an arrow in the after pseudo element that i want to rotate when clicked.

here is the styled component:

```
    export const Header = styled.div`
          padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem;
          &:after {
            content: url(${arrowUp});
            height: 100%;
            width: 15px;
            text-align: right;
            float: right;
            transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
`;
```

This is the React.ts component

```
export const AttributeValuesChecklist: React.FC<IProps> = ({
  title,
  name,
  values,
  valuesShowLimit = false,
  valuesShowLimitNumber = 5,
  onValueClick,
}: IProps) => {
  const [viewAllOptions, setViewAllOptions] = React.useState(!valuesShowLimit);

  const showAttributeList = e => {
    const actualDisplay = e.target.parentNode.children[1].style.display;
    if (actualDisplay === "block") {
      e.target.parentNode.children[1].style.display = "none";
    } else {
      e.target.parentNode.children[1].style.display = "block";
    }

  };

  return (
    <S.Wrapper>
      {title && (
        <S.Header onClick={e => showAttributeList(e)}>{title}</S.Header>
      )}
      <DropMenu>
        {values &&
          values.map((value, index) => {
            if (!viewAllOptions && index > valuesShowLimitNumber - 1) {
              return <></>;
            }
            return (
              <Checkbox
                name={name}
                checked={!!value.selected}
                onChange={() => onValueClick(value)}
              >
                {value && value.name}
              </Checkbox>
            );
          })}
      </DropMenu>
      <S.BottomBorder />
    </S.Wrapper>
  );
};
```

I've tried the "data-attribute" trick but it doesn't work. And beacuse i'm using styled-components i don't know how can I use premade classes.

Comment: Did the arrow successfully show up?

Comment: Yes, the arrow does show up and with the original rotation. I just can't figure out how to change the after property with JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//styled-component
export const Header = styled.div<{isClicked: boolean}>`
          padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem;
          &:after {
            content: url(${arrowUp});
            height: 100%;
            width: 15px;
            text-align: right;
            float: right;
            transform: ${props => props.isClicked ? rotate(180deg) : rotate(0deg)};
  }
`;

//component 
//you can make a state to store the value or pass from props
 <S.Header isClicked={//boolean value}>{title}</S.Header>
```

Comment: Loved it. I now know i can pass props to the styled component. Thank you.